# What product should I use to reseal an aggregate patio?

Tags: concrete

The surface was never really "smooth", but metal patio furniture with plastic gliders on its feet used to move easily across it. Now, the surface is rougher and pebbles are loose and get washed or swept away when cleaning the patio.  Is there a product I can pour/roll on to reseal the surface to prevent further loss of aggregate and restore its smoother finish?a

Comment: What is the patio made of? Have you tried washing and scrubbing any dirt off?

Comment: hes says "agregate" i assume that's "concrete wirh exposed agregate"